# Testing with Robot framework - Click navbar link in homepage after logging in failing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am testing a web application using the Robot framework and the Selenium2Library. I have tested successfully the login scenario, and now am trying to click on a link n the navbar in the homepage after logging in. The relevant part of my text file is given below:

```
*** Keywords ***
Go to login page
    Open Browser    ${HOMEPAGE}    ${BROWSER}

Login with invalid credentials should fail
    [Arguments]    ${username}    ${password}
    Input Text    id=userName    ${username}
    Input Text    id=passWord    ${password}
    Click Button    Login
    Page Should Contain    Password

Test Login 
    [Arguments]    ${username}    ${password}
    Input Text    id=userName    ${username}
    Input Text    id=passWord    ${password}
    Click Button    Login
    Page Should Contain    dashboard.php

Add Catalog
    Click Element   link=Catalog
    Page Should Contain    Add catalog
```

Unfortunately, when the Add Catalog test is run, I keep getting the error -

```
Test adding items to catalog                                          | FAIL |
ValueError: Element locator 'link=Catalog' did not match any elements.
```

I can't see the dashboard.php page opening after the previous tests complete successfully. The Catalog link is present on that page. Should I modify the `Add Catalog` keyword so that it somehow loads the dashboard.php page, or is my syntax for clicking on `Catalog` wrong? Please help!!

Comment: I am not sure to understand your situation/problem. "I can't see the dashboard.php page opening after the previous tests complete successfully" => you are talking about "test login" keyword? This kw does not leads you to the dashboard? By the way I don't understand what you mean by "Page Should Contain    dashboard.php"....  Please try to rephrase/explain more (show the test cases themselves, here we only have the keywords and we don't know how you call them)

Comment: What does the actual source html show for the element you are trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

As per code provided, once 'Test Login' keyword execute successfully then dashboard.php will display. In this page you are trying to click on link=Catalog.

As per provided question, you did not specified as dashboard.php is displayed or not after login or as is it taking some time to display that page?

If it is taking some time to display dashboard.php after login, then you need wait for some time. you may try below one at top which wait up to 15 sec

```
 Library | Selenium2Library | 15
```

Or else you can use below one before click on link in Add Catalog keyword

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible

if dashborad.php page displayed but still getting link error then try with another locator.

If dashboard.php page is not displaying after executing the 'Test Login' check that keyword again. Click on login button may not simulated correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the web app takes time to load, you need to insert wait conditions on your actions before you verify them.

```
Add Catalog
    Click Element   link=Catalog
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${SOME_ELEMENT_THAT_LOADS_LAST}
    Page Should Contain    Add catalog
```

Hope that helps